# Why does Stellar Partition Manager insist on keeping 128 MB "free space" on the medium?

Tags: macos, partition, external-disk, formatting, hfs+

I was just using Stellar Partition Manager to format a flash drive to HFS+. I deleted the current FAT32 partition and created a new HFS+ partition. I tried to make it as large as I could. Stellar wants to keep 128 MB as "FreeSpace".

[image]

I'm assuming there is some technical reason for this to have to be so. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to leave 128 MB after each partition is given in an [Apple's Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2166/_index.html):

> Note: We leave free space after each partition to make it easier for future system software to manipulate the partition map in ways that we can't anticipate currently.

In reality they adhere to their own policy only in special cases:

- Formatting a non-system disk to one or more partitions
- creating a Boot Camp partition

On a system disk there neither are 128 MB free spaces between partitions (EFI – system partition / system partition – Recovery HD) nor at the end.